# Error:1722 Getting session names

Tags: server, rpc, remote-desktop, remote-server

I am trying to check if anybody is connected to the server in my team with the following command: `query session /server:<SERVERNAME>`. But Every time I end up getting the following error:

> Error:1722 getting session names.
>
> Error[1722]: The RPC sever is unavailable.

I have already tried with qwinsta but i get the same issue in there too.
Is there anyway to get around the issue and get the required?

Answer (score 7):

launch regedit.exe (You have to be administrator to do that)
goto:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server

and change AllowRemoteRPC from the value 0 to the value 1
on each machine which should be able to receive a message

Comment: ps. here's a PowerShell script to wrap the `query session` function, which will apply the above registry setting if required to do so when the -Force parameter is added: https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/8173b2b8aeb84b0c0f4b48900e43a478/

Comment: Or simply REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v AllowRemoteRPC /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

Answer (score 1):

For me, the one Windows Server 2012 R2 giving this error was fixed by adding the following rule. None of the 97 other had the issue.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 135 RPC" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=135
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 135 RPC" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=135
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 445 RPC" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=445
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 445 RPC" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=445
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sharing a folder in the target computer, also store credentials of target user in the source computer.

eg:msg /Server: targetipaddress targetUsername  "Message"